# Parsing deeply nested JSON with pandas json_normalize

Tags: pandas, python-2.7

I can't seem to extract all the metadata I need from nested json using json_normalize. Refer to JSON below. I'm trying to retrieve title ("Some Book") from the content node but I'm only successful going as deep as content.

For example:

```
json_normalize(result_data, 'data', ['title', 'key',['group_dimensions','content']])
```

produces

```
,date,units,group_dimensions.content,key,title
0,2019-03-17T00:00:00.000Z,0.0,"{u'key': u'1358883623', u'title': u'Some Book'}",143489,Czech Republic
1,2019-03-24T00:00:00.000Z,10.0,"{u'key': u'1358883623', u'title': u'Some Book'}",143489,Czech Republic
2,2019-03-31T00:00:00.000Z,13.0,"{u'key': u'1358883623', u'title': u'Some Book'}",143489,Czech Republic
3,2019-03-17T00:00:00.000Z,0.0,"{u'key': u'1358883623', u'title': u'Some Book'}",143487,Romania
```

But I still need to extract 'title'. But going one level deeper:

```
json_normalize(result_data, 'data', ['title', 'key',['group_dimensions',['content','title']]])
```

produces an error:
TypeError: sequence item 1: expected string, list found

Ideas?

```
import json
import pandas as pd
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

result_data = [
 {
  "title": "Czech Republic", 
  "group_dimensions": {
   "content": {
    "key": "123456789", 
    "title": "Some Book"
   }, 
   "store_front_ica": {
    "key": "143489", 
    "title": "Czech Republic"
   }
  }, 
  "data": [
   {
    "date": "2019-03-17T00:00:00.000Z", 
    "units": 0.0
   }, 
   {
    "date": "2019-03-24T00:00:00.000Z", 
    "units": 10.0
   }, 
   {
    "date": "2019-03-31T00:00:00.000Z", 
    "units": 13.0
   }
  ], 
  "key": "143489", 
  "metadata": {
   "key": "143489", 
   "title": "Czech Republic"
  }
 }, 
 {
  "title": "Romania", 
  "group_dimensions": {
   "content": {
    "key": "123456789", 
    "title": "Some Book"
   }, 
   "store_front_ica": {
    "key": "143487", 
    "title": "Romania"
   }
  }, 
  "data": [
   {
    "date": "2019-03-17T00:00:00.000Z", 
    "units": 0.0
   }, 
   {
    "date": "2019-03-24T00:00:00.000Z", 
    "units": 0.0
   }, 
   {
    "date": "2019-03-31T00:00:00.000Z", 
    "units": 200.0
   }
  ], 
  "key": "143487", 
  "metadata": {
   "key": "143487", 
   "title": "Romania"
  }
 }
]
```

Comment: `res_df = pd.io.json.json_normalize(result_data, 'data', ['title', 'key',['group_dimensions','content', 'title']])` worked for me, IIUC.

Comment: That worked! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following package that I made. It will expand every `dict` that it fill found in the DataFrame.

```
import flat_table
# I am selecting group dimentions, key, metadata, and title.
df = pd.DataFrame(result_data).iloc[:,1:]
flat_table.normalize(df)
```

It will find all dictionaries and expand as new columns.

```
   index store_front_ica.title store_front_ica.key content.title content.key  key_x         title_x         title_y   key_y
0      0        Czech Republic              143489     Some Book   123456789 143489  Czech Republic  Czech Republic  143489
1      1               Romania              143487     Some Book   123456789 143487         Romania         Romania  143487
```

The package also expands lists into rows, here is the full `df`.

```
   index  units                      date store_front_ica.title  store_front_ica.key content.title content.key   key_x         title_x        title_y   key_y
0      0    0.0  2019-03-17T00:00:00.000Z        Czech Republic               143489     Some Book   123456789  143489  Czech Republic Czech Republic  143489 
1      0   10.0  2019-03-24T00:00:00.000Z        Czech Republic               143489     Some Book   123456789  143489  Czech Republic Czech Republic  143489 
2      0   13.0  2019-03-31T00:00:00.000Z        Czech Republic               143489     Some Book   123456789  143489  Czech Republic Czech Republic  143489 
3      1    0.0  2019-03-17T00:00:00.000Z               Romania               143487     Some Book   123456789  143487         Romania        Romania  143487 
4      1    0.0  2019-03-24T00:00:00.000Z               Romania               143487     Some Book   123456789  143487         Romania        Romania  143487 
5      1  200.0  2019-03-31T00:00:00.000Z               Romania               143487     Some Book   123456789  143487         Romania        Romania  143487
```

You can try the [flat-table](https://pypi.org/project/flat-table/).